# What are the dimensions of angular velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, dimensional-analysis, angular-velocity

My friend said that angular velocity has dimensions of $T^{-1}$. Or equivalently, it's measured in $\text{rad}/\text{s}$, and $\text{rad}$ is dimensionless, leaving only the $1/\text{s}$.

But I think that angular velocity should have the same units $L \, T^{-1}$ as translational velocity, because both of them are velocities. Shouldn't the angular velocity be the distance traveled along the circumference per unit time? How could the dimensions differ?

Comment: Your are mistaken. One way of giving the angular velocity is $\omega=\frac{|v| \sin{\theta}}{|r|}$ which gives $\frac{\frac{L}{T}}{L}=\frac{1}{T}$.
We are talking about a change in angle over time, the spatial dimension is given by the $r$ radial distance from the origin without which the angular velocity has no meaning.

Comment: @Feyre that should probably be posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $T^{-1}$.  Consider a rod of length $l$, marked at $l/4$, $l/2$ and $3l/4$, and let it rotate with angular velocity $\omega$ about the centre ($l/2$) point.  Now quite clearly the end points are moving twice as fast -- they cover twice the distance per unit time --  as the points marked $l/4$ and $3l/4$, so the dimensions can not be $L/T$, as the whole rod has the same angular velocity.  In fact the dimensions are $\mathrm{angle}/T$, but angle, being the ratio of two lengths (diameter and circumference), is dimensionless, giving dimensions of $T^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The physical angular velocity is angular displacement divided by time interval. The dimension of angular displacement is angle (**A**); the dimension of time interval is time (**T**). So the dimension of angular velocity is **A**/**T**.

Confusingly, what is commonly known as "angle" (e.g. in the SI) is the radian measure of the angle: if theta is an angle (dimension **A**), the corresponding SI "angle" is its radian measure, "theta" = theta/rad (dimension **A**/**A** = **1**). The SI "radian" is the radian measure of 1 radian: "rad" = (1 rad)/rad = 1.

The radian measure of theta, theta/rad, is the number of radians in theta--i.e. a number (dimension **1**). So what is called "angular velocity" (in the SI and almost everywhere else) is the number of radians swept out (dimension **1**) divided by the time interval (dimension **T**): its dimension is **1**/**T**. In other words, (SI) "angular velocity" is the actual physical angular velocity divided by one radian.

As an example, if theta = 20 pi rad (dimension **A**) and t = 10 s, the (actual physical) angular velocity is omega = (20 pi rad)/(10 s) = 2 pi rad/s. The SI "angular velocity is: "omega" = omega/rad = 2 pi (rad/rad)/s = 2 pi 1/s = 2 pi "rad"/s. [The SI helpfully explains that 1 can be replaced by (the SI) "rad" where appropriate (the quotation marks are not used).]

The well-known widespread confusion permeating this subject stems from the ubiquitous formula:

"theta" = (s/r)

where "theta" is said to be "measured in radians." What this actually means is that "theta" is the numerical value of theta when theta is expressed in radians: theta/rad--i.e. the radian measure of theta. So the formula is actually:

theta/rad = (s/r)

This is dimensionally consistent: dim(LHS) = **A**/**A** = **1**; dim(RHS) = **L**/**L** = **1**.

Rearranging for theta:

theta = (s/r) rad

Keeping rad EXPLICITLY in the formulas for rotational kinematics and dynamics dispels the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your are mistaken. One way of giving the angular velocity is $\omega=\frac{|v| \sin{\theta}}{|r|}$ which gives $\frac{\frac{L}{T}}{L}=\frac{1}{T}$.
We are talking about a change in angle over time, the spatial dimension is given by the $r$ radial distance from the origin without which the angular velocity has no meaning.

I always recommend writing all dimensions down when doing physics exercises, this gives you an intuition of all the units involved, and is a useful way of double checking your answers.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I thought that something with name 'Velocity' always have m/s units, but it's not. And thanks for your advice as well. After a second thought, circumference per unit time is equal to velocity, not angular velocity :)